# Throwing errors in Cosmos DB stored procedure and catching in C#

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos DB requires stored procedures written in JavaScript to perform transactions (cf. [Cosmos DB server-side programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions)).

I then call that stored procedure from C#.

When throwing an error in such stored procedures, I would like to be able to deduce what type of error was thrown (e.g. by including an error code).

The exception being returned to my caller is of type `DocumentClientException` with a status code of `400 Bad request`. If I throw an object, such as `throw {Code: 1, Text: "Some text"};` I get `Exception = [object Object]` back as part of the error *message*, if I instead do `throw "Some text";`, get `Exception = Some text`.

Is there a way to get the object that was thrown as JSON, or some other way to know which error was thrown, apart from attempting to parse the error message text (which is partly text from Cosmos DB and partly from what was thrown)?

Comment: Not sure what you want.Do you want to get the details of error message?

Comment: No, I want to find a good way to know in C# what error I threw in the stored procedure, without resorting to parsing the error message text.

Comment: I created this issue regarding this problem: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/48

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way at the moment. In my stored procedures, I throw an Error object with some JSON message. On the C# side, I parse the Exception to get to my JSON error object and de-serialize that.

Comment: How do you get the json message? I Just get "Exception = [object Object]" back if I throw a json object.

Comment: @yngling: you should stringify the content of your error on stored procedure side.